# Unable to display unicode character in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I have several programs (Notepad, [Google PinYin](http://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/ime/pinyin/), ...) which can display Chinese unicode without problem under Windows 8. Be it Simplified Chinese or Traditional Chinese.

However, when comes to my new Windows 8, I get the following problem

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note, **change the "Language for non-unicode programs" won't help**. As in old Windows 7, I still leave it as *English* too. Since Notepad and Google PinYin both support unicode, they can display both Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese very well.

[image]

For font setting, I change remove *Hide fonts based on language settings*. But, that won't help.

[image]

Comment: I think you made a typo, when you first said "windows 8" did you mean 7?

Comment: I do mention "old", right? My previous OS is Windows 7. I just bought a laptop which comes with Windows 8 recently.

Answer (score 2):

I know why now. My purchased laptop comes with

*Windows 8 **Single Language**, English (64bit)*

Time for me to switch to Ubuntu Linux.